# PHP hitcounter adds symbol before digit for each hit

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, flock, hitcounter

I got stuck in a small problem. I have a php-page:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
include( 'counter.php' );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the file **counter.php**

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r+");

if(!$fp){
    error_log("Could not open counter.txt");
    exit();
}

if(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    error_log("Could not lock");
}
else{
    $counter = intval(fread($fp, filesize("counter.txt")));
    $counter++;

    echo $counter;
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    fwrite($fp, $counter);  // set your data
    fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

and the file **counter.txt**, which has the content "0" (0)

After running index.php once, the textfile content becomes ^@^@1, and after that it becomes ^@^@^@1

What I want is the 0 to become 1, and then 2

Is there something wrong the code?

It's running on Ubuntu 18, with Apache, and the files with rights are

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 emanuel www-data  559 Feb 13 21:56 counter.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 emanuel www-data   11 Feb 13 22:51 counter.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 emanuel www-data  128 Feb 13 22:50 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 2 emanuel www-data 4096 Feb 12 14:55 software
```

Answer would be appreciated

Comment: personally I would have used `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` with the `LOCK_EX` flag.  - but that's me.  Also it would cut your code in about half.

Comment: `the textfile content becomes ^@^@1,` what does the echo statement say?

Comment: Thanks, @ArtisticPhoenix, echo say just "1"

Comment: Are you 100% sure no other code is modifying this file?

Comment: In addition you should explicitly cast the `$counter` into a string `(string) $counter` and you can use the `declare(strict_types=1)` constraint.  Further more create the file if it does not exist and use `$counter = ($fsize = filesize("counter.txt")) ? intval(fread($fp, $fsize)) : 0;` to initialize the conter when the file is empty. Otherwise `fread` throws an error due to zero size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Rewind after ftruncate (took a bit of work to isolate it)

```
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    rewind($fp); //rewind the pointer
```

Or you can just use `rewind` instead of `ftruncate`, which seems to be the cause of the `\0` null bytes.  It seems somewhat pointless to do both as if you write after doing rewind it wipes the file out anyway (unless you use `a+` append) ...

Looking in the doc's the very first example uses both.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php

From PHP.net

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('output.txt', 'r+');

fwrite($handle, 'Really long sentence.');
rewind($handle);
fwrite($handle, 'Foo');
rewind($handle);

echo fread($handle, filesize('output.txt'));

fclose($handle);
?>
```

Even though the reason why is not explained...  I just use `rewind()` but I am always lazy so I endeavor to write the least amount of code that I need to, as I write a LOT of code.

**Another solution**

Trim the contents of your file before using `intval`

```
  $counter = intval(trim(fread($fp, filesize("counter.txt"))));
```

In notepad++

```
  [null][null]1
```

[image]

Anyway that was a fun one... thanks!

Comment: This does not prevent concurrency in race condition. Two instances can read at the same time but the result will only be +1. Locking as shown in the question is the correct way to do such kind of task.

Comment: That's a good point....  But sometimes it can be useful to see if the issue is with "this" code or if somewhere else.   I don't see any reason for the problem and if it happens when using `file_put_contents` then some other piece of code is modifying the file.

Comment: Hello, I removed the ending ?> in the code.php - no effect

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - I tested your first suggestion, and 2nd, both worked!

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - thanks, both work, I mistyped (in php)

Comment: That's Kool, when I opened the file in `notepad++`  it wasn't `^@` but `nul` which is a null byte char `\0`  and trim will remove those.  Though I am not sure why they are their.  In most cases these are not shown as part of a string so that is why the `echo` is different.

Comment: The weird thing is that the original code gets a `0` when reading inproper encoded file. It actually increases to 1. The question is why `ftruncate` does not work properly in this case.

Comment: We ran into a trap. `ftruncate` is ok here, however, it is not documented that is changes the file pointer as well. lol Thus it must be set explicitly as well. The correct answer can be reduced to use trancate for all cases (incremention is not expected to generate shorter numbers in this case) and rewind to set the new write position.

Comment: Ha we all learned something I guess, Don't tell anyone I never use `ftruncate` in like 9 years of PHP programing ... lol  ... or if I did I forgot about it.

Comment: I also do not remember I ever used truncate in PHP. :D It's so counter intuitive that writing behind the end of file is even possible.

Comment: I suggest to move the correct solution and explaination of the issue to the top if you do not want to remove the alternative (bad) workarounds.

Comment: Good I idea, I tend to do work in the answer as I figure things out. It's just my process... lol ... I knew `trim` wasn't the correct solution as that is a bandaid fix.  It's always better to fix something by doing *Less* than the original.  I find a lot of time buggy code is just overly complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188370/discussion-between-quasimodos-clone-and-artisticphoenix).